# JQuery - accessing a VAR in a function which I will need in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, function

Ok so in my html/js i have a form that updates based on the users previous selection. On the last stage i have a select menu where the user will choose their city.  I have stored the value of the selected item in my Options list with the id #myCity to the following.

```
('#myCity').change(function(){
    var CityValue = $("#myCity").val();
});
```

Once that value is set, my form then displays the submit button

```
<input type="submit" id="go" value="Submit" onclick="getweather()" />
```

This is where i start to have a bit of bother. In my getweather() function i want to be able to take the var CityValue from above and append it to another var so i can load a specific page.

```
function getweather(){
                    var CityValue;
                    var to_load = 'getweather.php?p='+ CityValue +'.html';

                    $('#weather').empty().append(to_load);


                 }
```

but in my testing i do not think that my getweather() function is able to read my desired var.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the `CityValue` only in the function scope that you cannot access from outside. Either declare your variable globally:

```
var CityValue;
$('#myCity').change(function(){
    CityValue = $("#myCity").val();
});
function getweather() {
    var to_load = 'getweather.php?p='+ encodeURIComponent(CityValue) +'.html';
    $('#weather').empty().append(to_load);
}
```

Or just call `$("#myCity").val()` in your `getweather` function:

```
function getweather() {
    var to_load = 'getweather.php?p='+ encodeURIComponent($("#myCity").val()) +'.html';
    $('#weather').empty().append(to_load);
}
```

Comment: Where do you suggest i put the getweather() function?  A demo of my problem can be found here http://chrismj.com/

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first function you specified (the event handler for onchange) doesn't do anything right now. You can just remove it and edit the second function like this:

```
function getweather(){
    var CityValue = $("#myCity").val();

    var to_load = 'getweather.php?p='+ CityValue +'.html';

    $('#weather').empty().append(to_load);
}
```

Comment: Where do you suggest i put the getweather() function? A demo of my problem can be found here http://chrismj.com

Answer (score 0):

> Well, the first function you specified (the event handler for onchange) doesn't do anything right now. You can just remove it and edit the second function like this:

You can then add this function call to the change event.

```
function getweather(){
    var CityValue = $("#myCity").val();

    var to_load = 'getweather.php?p='+ CityValue +'.html';

    $('#weather').empty().append(to_load);
}

$('#myCity').change(getweather);
```

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant answer to the question is in using [jQuery data API](http://api.jquery.com/data/). This allows you to store arbitrary data within an object rather than declaring variables, keeping everything in a nice OOP manner. So, to do what you want would mean storing the value like so:

```
$('#myCity').change(function(){
   $("#myCity").data("CityValue", $("#myCity").val());
});
```

This way you would be able to retrieve it like so:

```
function getweather(){
   var to_load = 'getweather.php?p='+ $("#myCity").data("CityValue") +'.html';
   $('#weather').empty().append(to_load);
}
```